# Downloading limited items from Azure Blob

Tags: azure

Working with a Silver light app accessing Blob storage.
We have an azure blob where we store all our wave files (about 10k-15k).
The grid to which the blob items are bound uses QueryableDomainServiceCollectionView to create a biding data context.
The ListBlob method is invoked everytime the QDSCV is invoked thereby
Everytime we access the blob all the 15k files are downloaded. Is there a way

1. To download limited items from blob every time we need say 10 files only 10 are downloaded.
2. Next paging results in getting the next 20, instead of getting all at once?
   This is causing a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The ListBlob API supports a Top operation with continuation tokens.  It is exposed in the [ListBlobsSegmented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff361722.aspx) method if you are using the client.  Just call this method, pass the max result size you wish (< 5000, IIRC).  Subsequent calls you can just use [GetNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff361742.aspx) method on your partial results.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I read this up, the first time ListBlobsSegmented is invoked can I say the limit of items to say 10 blobs? Looks like there are 2 overloads the first overload takes in "options" only and the second one has a "max results" but also asks for a continuation token. I need to get only 10 results at a time from the first time i invoke ListBlobsSegmented. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried to pass null for the continuationToken the first time?  I would guess that would do what you want.

Comment: Yes Thank you so much I tried just that a while back and it worked!

Comment: What I am trying out now is to associate it with a datagrid for paging. Also how would I be able to get the 100 latest blobs uploaded? Do I need to have the metadata updated for it when its uploaded with timestamp?

Comment: Struggling with this again. Is there anyway I can get blob items by Metadata, blob items uploaded in the order of the latest/last ones which were uploaded/modified?